# Is there a mono alternative for IIRF isapi rewrite filter?

Tags: asp.net, mono, nginx, cherokee, iirf

I'm moving some ASP.NET projects from IIS to Cherokee/nginx and I need a solution for url rewriting. I'm using [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) (great project) but this works only on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url rewriting is a built-in handler in Cherokee:

http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_redir.html

You should be able to take care of url rewriting with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that nginx also have [similar module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule). Thanks marapet for pointing the right direction.